# List for abstact objects

Tags: c++, list, inheritance

It s my 1st question but it s very improtant for me.
Language: C++, I would like to use

```
 #include <list>
```

I have the abstract classes:

- `Organism`.
- `Animal` which inherits from `Organism`.
- `Plant` which inherits from `Organism`.

Then I have classes like `Wolf`, `Sheep`, etc. They all inherit from `Animal`.

At the end I have classes like `Oak`, `Grass`, etc. They all inherit from `Plant`.

How can I create list having all those elements? `list<Organism> my_list;`
 doesn't work.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? Show your work!

Comment: You and everyone else tonight who realized this is due tomorrow.

Comment: @KerrekSB Hey, don't make me panic like that! I almost believed we were Sunday night!

Comment: @Quentin: It sure feels like it! :-)

Comment: You should read about Polymorphism in C++!

Answer (score 1):

In a big shortcut, you have to use polymorphism and your list should contain pointers of base type, which point to concrete objects.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Organism
{
    public:
    virtual string getName() const
    {
        cout<<"organism"<<endl;
        return name;
    }
    protected:
    string name;
};

    class Animal : public Organism
    {
        public:
        virtual string getName() const
        {
            cout<<"animal"<<endl;
            return name;
        }
    };

class Plant : public Organism
{
    public:
    virtual string getName() const
    {
        cout<<"plant"<<endl;
        return name;
    }
};

int main() {
    list<Organism*> objects;
    Organism *ob1 = new Animal();
    Organism *ob2 = new Plant();
    objects.push_back(ob1);
    objects.push_back(ob2);
    for(auto it : objects)
    {
        it->getName();
    }
    for(auto it : objects)
    {
        delete it;  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is only example, you can use smart pointers or just call delete on your elements.

Comment: You now added code to got your memory properly lean, so I deleted my 1st comment.